# Using both hCaptcha and reCAPTCHA at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, hcaptcha

In order to combat bots on my website, I'd like to use both hCaptcha and reCAPTCHA v3 (invisible challenge) at the same time. I've got the backend code ready, but I'm having a problem with the front-end. hCaptcha's scripts seem to override the value of `window.grecaptcha` with its own `window.hcaptcha`, and thus throwing errors when I run the reCAPTCHA v3 challenge (via `grecaptcha.execute()`).

Is there any way to stop hCaptcha from doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Disable that behaviour with the `recaptchacompat` parameter.

> recaptchacompat,  on | off,   Optional. Whether or not to insert
> window.grecaptcha compatibility hook. Defaults to on.
>
> https://docs.hcaptcha.com/configuration/

i.e. `<script src="https://js.hcaptcha.com/1/api.js?recaptchacompat=off" async defer></script>`